# Getting exception while hitting get request in http module listener in any \point platform studio

Tags: http, exception, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, illegalargumentexception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXbkg.png)

Following issue is faced when trryin to hit mule app through postman using get api
which has following screenshot of error.

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots for textual errors. Instead edit your question and add the text of the log. Also share the flow that receives the request (as XML text please). Kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 for guidance on how to ask questions.

Comment: For reference the root error is `Unsupported class file major version 61`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a Mule project with Java JDK or OpenJDK 17. Neither Anypoint Studio nor any version of Mule supports Java 17. Please select a supported version of Java. For Mule 4.4 -the version that your project is using- the versions supported are mentioned in the [requirements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/hardware-and-software-requirements#required-software): JDK 1.8.0 or JDK 11.

To resolve it either use the default version or [configure a compatible version](https://docs.mulesoft.com/studio/7.11/change-jdk-config-in-projects#select-the-jre-version-for-all-your-studio-projects) to execute the project.